# TableView horizontal scrolling according to cell width

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have table view inside scroll view which will scroll according to table view cell width.I have set the scroll view from top,bottom,leading and trailing.Then I have given the same constraints to view inside the scroll view including centerX and centerY.Then for horizontal scrolling I have set the trailing and centerX priority to 250.But my table view is not scrolling.I want to set it through autolayout.

I want the table to scroll horizontally if label increases inside the table view cell.

This is my view hierarchy

[image]

Comment: tableview does not scroll horizontally, use collection view.

Comment: i don't have to scroll the table view cell but I have to scroll the tableview itself.

Comment: Do you think to scroll the tableview you need additional scrollview??

Comment: Actually your scrollview that you added outside the tableview, it must be inside the cell and then add your labels. Scrollview content size must be calculated with the label size.

Comment: I have already tried it but i want to scroll my table view not the cell inside.

Comment: Use collectionview then, here is the sample project -> https://github.com/akashraje/BidirectionalCollectionViewLayout .. You might get more demos if you search on google. There are lots of answer on stackView, you can check those too.

Answer (score -1):

@Zahid I made a public example on github with what I wrote about below:

https://github.com/amichnia/stack-54735700

Original answer:

As it was already said, table views do not scroll horizontally in general. **But no one said you can't put table view inside UIScrollView that scrolls horizontally**. There would be some challenges here though:

1. I don't think autolayout with autoresizing cells would work good.
2. You need to figure out scrollview/tableview gesture recognizers order. You can use UIGestureRecognizer delegate methods to resolve their collisions
3. You need to determine width of the table view. You can do it with old nasty way:

   - compute size of every cell first,
   - take max of these sizes
   - set it to table view width
   - reload data

Is it worth the hassle? That's your call to take.

With your setup (I see scroll view as root view) the simplest (but not best) option would be to disable scrolling on table view, enable scrolling both directions on scroll view, and just update whole table view size. **It will work well only with small amount of cells though!**

Comment: Are you serious with the answer? If you stop scrolling of tableView then how you do dequeue ???

Comment: OPs TableView is not static that means he have to show multiple cells may be 100 but your case is only valid if there is 3-4 cells that all can be shown in a single tableview load. Its not a mislead, just do good practice.

Comment: I have encountered 2 issues in your demo, 1. Change your cellForRow with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOGD8.png) and check the UI output. 2. You used `tableViewHeight.constant = CGFloat(50 * items)` for tableView height, what if every cell have different height. Does it still work?

Comment: @daiha_boy That's the challenge. As you've seen the whole table view has a height that's setup upfront, same with the width.

To make it "dynamic" (one of the possibilities):
1. You can do "prerender" pass, before doing tableView.reloadData()
2. In this pass, you deque cells and compute their size, keeping:
  a) Biggest width so far - maxWidth
  b) Sum of the heights from all cells - sumHeight
3. After that, you can:
  1. Set tableview width constant to that maxWidth
  2. Set tableview height constant to that sumHeight
4. Call reload data

It was done that way before autoresize